# Devolver resta entre mayor y menor en array

Tags: javascript, array

Devolver la resta entre el valor mas grande y menos grande del array.

```
function mayorMenosMenor(arr) {
    // Obtener del array "arr" el número mayor y el menor. Devuelve la resta entre los mismos
    // NOTA: No utilizar los métodos "min" y "max" de "Math".
    //
    // Tu código:
    var max = arr[0];
    var min = arr[0];

    for(var i = 1; i < arr.length; i++){
        if(arr[i]>max){
            max = arr[i]
        }
        if(arr[i]>min){
            min = arr[i]
        }
    }
    return (max-min);
};
```

Comment: ¿Cuál es tu duda o pregunta? Te invito a leer [ask].

Answer (score 2):

```js
function mayorMenosMenor(arr) {
    // Inicializas las variables "max" y "min"
    var max = 0;
    var min = Infinity;

    //Recorres el array
    for(var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
        // Si el valor del array donde nos encontramos es mas grande que "max", max = valor del array
        if(arr[i]>max){
            max = arr[i]
        }
         // Si el valor del array donde nos encontramos es mas menor que "min", min = valor del array
        if(arr[i]<min){
            min = arr[i]
        }
    }
    // Return de la resta entre max y min
    return (max-min);
}

console.log(mayorMenosMenor([3,5,7,9,1000]));
```

Comment: Si necesitas alguna aclaración o esto no soluciona tu problema escribe un comentario!

Comment: Tu codigo está bien excepto que el minimo no debe iniciar en 0, debe iniciar en numero muy grande. De lo contrario todo numero positivo que pase por el for no sera guardado como minimo. Edite la respuesta y asigne `Infinity` a min.